# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'" related to Conda env

Tags: pytorch, anaconda

I tried to run a Python file (not mine) and this occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fname/.conda/envs/ptsne/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 348, in _check_seekable
    f.seek(f.tell())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_builder.py", line 29, in <module>
    map_location=dev)
  File "/home/fname/.conda/envs/ptsne/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 771, in load
    with _open_file_like(f, 'rb') as opened_file:
  File "/home/fname/.conda/envs/ptsne/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 275, in _open_file_like
    return _open_buffer_reader(name_or_buffer)
  File "/home/fname/.conda/envs/ptsne/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 260, in __init__
    _check_seekable(buffer)
  File "/home/fname/.conda/envs/ptsne/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 351, in _check_seekable
    raise_err_msg(["seek", "tell"], e)
  File "/home/fname/.conda/envs/ptsne/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 344, in raise_err_msg
    raise type(e)(msg)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'. You can only torch.load from a file that is seekable. Please pre-load the data into a buffer like io.BytesIO and try to load from it instead.
```

I'm using `file_builder.py` from [this repository](https://github.com/Academich/reaction_space_ptsne).

Is that solely because of Conda or is something wrong with that file?  How to fix it?

I haven't tried anything yet, as I have no idea what to begin with.

Comment: What command are you using? Just `python file_builder.py`? I think you maybe need to [make sure you're including the filename of the model in your command](https://github.com/hkchengrex/CascadePSP/issues/4). Similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I haven't added commands like `--output`, `--device`, etc. that can be found in the `file_builder.py` source (in `parser.add_argument(...)`). There were no instructions on how to use this file, so I figured it out myself.